# How to mention -profile in ant <javac> JDK8

Tags: java, ant, java-8

I want to compile my java code in JDK8 "compact profile 2". How to mention this "-profile" in  task. I am using apache ant 1.9.2. I tried to execute this below written  target, but it failed saying **javac doesn't support the "profile" attribute**. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<javac destdir="${@{module}.classes.dir}"
               encoding="UTF-8"
               debug="${javac.debug}"
               debuglevel="${javac.debuglevel}"
               optimize="${javac.optimize}"
               deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
               verbose="${javac.verbose}"
               target="${javac.target}"
               source="${javac.source}"
               profile="compact2"
               listfiles="${javac.listfiles}"
               includeAntRuntime="no"
               includeJavaRuntime="no"
               excludes="${ade.files}, **/package-info.java"
               classpathref="@{module}.classpath.refid">
            <compilerarg line="${javac.warnlevel}" />
            <src refid="@{module}.sourcepath.refid" />
        </java>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-profile` option, along with other `javac` command options, can be specified using the nested `compilerarg` element:

```
<javac destdir="${@{module}.classes.dir}"
           encoding="UTF-8"
           debug="${javac.debug}"
           debuglevel="${javac.debuglevel}"
           optimize="${javac.optimize}"
           deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
           verbose="${javac.verbose}"
           target="${javac.target}"
           source="${javac.source}"
           listfiles="${javac.listfiles}"
           includeAntRuntime="no"
           includeJavaRuntime="no"
           excludes="${ade.files}, **/package-info.java"
           classpathref="@{module}.classpath.refid">
        <compilerarg line="${javac.warnlevel}" />
        <compilerarg line="-profile compact2" />
        <src refid="@{module}.sourcepath.refid" />
</java>
```